# Find and Update XMPP version on ubuntu server running Openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire, ubuntu-18.04

This question may sound absurd as I am totally new to XMPP & Openfire. I have a setup of Openfire 4.2.3 in Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS that being used in my android chat app. During testing I received a Timeout error. While investigating the issue I found the solution rely on the XMPP updated version, check this [link](https://github.com/xmppjs/xmpp.js/issues/592) for more info.

Well I tried my best to find out my XMPP version and how to update it. Unfortunately I didn't find anything on it. So, I have two obvious questions here:

1. How to check XMPP version my Openfire is running on?
2. How to update XMPP version on my existing Openfire setup?

Comment: Are you able to use the web-interface: http://localhost:9090 ?

Comment: yes I am able to use web-interface using ServerIP:9090

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to use the web-interface, just log in. On the start page look for the server properties. Theres the version.

[image: Screenshot]

For upgrading follow these steps:

> 1. To stop openfire on ubuntu: /etc/init.d/openfire stop;
> 2. Backup copy of the openfire installation directory: /usr/share/openfire;
> 3. Backup Openfire Base in Postgres: If you use the pgAdmin application, right-click on openfire base and click “Backup”. To run backup, it can be with own postgres as user. I recommend tar format, and encoding “SQL_ASCII”.
> 4. To install the new version: you can actually use the “dpkg -i” command, you will be asked if you want to keep your current version (choose this one), but you will still upgrade (option N or O - keep your currently -installed version).
> 5. On the java, has a statement informing that from version 4.3 will be necessary Java 8 installed.

Source: https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/update-openfire-4-1-6-to-4-2-1-in-ubuntu-server/80336

And if you really meant the "XMPP-Version". There is not really such a thing. XMPP is implemented to a different extend on different server-providers.  Some have more extensions, some less.
To see which ones you have, refer to the wikipedia site:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XMPP_server_software

Comment: That is the Openfire version, I am looking for the xmpp version. Currently the latest xmpp version is 0.7.3. source : https://github.com/xmppjs/xmpp.js/releases.

Comment: @VipiNNegi What you are refering to is just a js-library for xmpp to communicate with the server. Like I said XMPP itself has no version. Just more or less integrated specs per server. This is the official git of XMPP: https://github.com/xsf/xmpp.org.

Comment: thanks, now I have some insight on the subject, if so, how do I check whether this lib is installed in my Openfire setup. If yes how do I update it? It seems to be the only way  to fix the current issue of my application.